# Where can I find resources to learn about change-point analysis ?

Tags: r, time-series, references, change-point

Where can I find resources to learn about change-point analysis ?

Hopefully, someone can advise me a **textbook** to read and it will cover both univariate change-point analysis and *multivariate* change-point analysis.

It will also be very helpful if someone can point me to some resources, which contains a worked example (using change-point analysis) using R.

So, I understand the theoretical material and the applied material. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: [Here's a decent blog post on change-point analysis](http://www.r-bloggers.com/changepoint-analysis-of-time-series/). Also, a related post here on CV: [Change point analysis](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/59755/32036). Plenty of references listed at [Changepoint.info](http://www.changepoint.info/introduction.html), including a book ([Chen & Gupta, 2012](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/applied+probability+and+statistics/book/978-0-8176-4800-8)).

Comment: There's an R package changepoint with an accompanying paper in the Journal of Statistical software: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v58/i03/paper

Comment: I wrote a survey paper on change point analysis in an actuarial context if that may help you: https://www.casact.org/abstract/survey-approaches-changepoint-problem-actuarial-context