# Trend analysis for change in multivariate distribution over time

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, trend, test-for-trend

At each time point, I have a multivariate distribution $x=[x_1,x_2,x_3]$. I don't have that many time points around 3-15. I would like to know whether the change of the distribution over the time is significant. I checked out the Mann-Kendall trend test but it only works for a single value at each time point.

Do you guys know some good test for this? For a univariate distribution is fine with me as well.

Comment: You could look at [changepoint analysis](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59755/change-point-analysis).

Comment: Thank you very much. I should be more precise since I am interested in more in monotonic trends.